# Use dependency from boot file in other boot file in Quasar (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to use an instance of an object in a boot file where the instance is created in another boot file. The documentation [0] talks about using an object instance from a boot file and it works fine when using the instance in a component. I would like to access the instance in another boot file.

First boot file that creates the instance looks like this:

```js
import { AuthService } from '../authorization/AuthService';

let oidc = null
export default ({ router, store, Vue }) => {
  const OIDC = new AuthService();
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const allowAnonymous = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.allowAnonymous)
    if (allowAnonymous) {
      next()
    } else {
      var isAuthenticated = OIDC.isAuthenticated()
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        next()
      } else {
        OIDC.signIn()
      }
    }
  })

  Vue.prototype.$oidc = OIDC
  oidc = OIDC
}

export { oidc }
```

And I am trying to use the `oidc` instance in another boot file like this:

```js
import oidc from "boot/oidc-service"
import axios from 'axios'

let axiosInstance = null;
export default ({ app, router, store, Vue }) => {
    const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: window.env.BASE_URL
    })
  
    AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
      return oidc.getAccessToken().then(token => {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`

        return config
      })
    }, (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
    
    Vue.prototype.$axios = AxiosInstance
    axiosInstance = AxiosInstance
}

export { axiosInstance }
```

I import them in the following order:

```json
    boot: [
      'oidc-service',
      'axios',
...
```

If I export the class instead of the instance, I can instantiate it and code works as expected. I would like for the `oidc` object to be a singleton however.

How can I use the instance of `oidc` in my axios setup?

[0] https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#Accessing-data-from-boot-files

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something... if `oidc` is not null, return it, otherwise continue with the initialization:

```js
import { AuthService } from '../authorization/AuthService';

let oidc = null
export default ({ router, store, Vue }) => {
    if(oidc !== null) return oidc;
    // else continue...
```

Comment: How would oidc ever not be null in this snippet?

Comment: @geoidesic oidc is null the first time the file is loaded.  The check ensures that the oidc is a singleton--initialized only once, regardless of how many boot files (or other things) import it.

Comment: I haven't had the time to try this yet but will have a look. It seems contradictory to me though since "Boot files fulfill one special purpose: they run code before the App’s Vue root component is instantiated". If they are executed before the app root is build, the boot file that returns null will not do the initialisation it needs. -https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files#when-to-use-boot-files

Comment: I've been using Quasar (and boot files) for over 2 years.  It works.  And it has less to do with quasar and more to do with how Javascript (ESM) modules work in general.  You can always write some [small amount of code to prove it out](https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/javascript_modules_es_6_modules).